# how to stop Pentaho' PAC from searching non-existant hsqldb instance?

Tags: mysql, hsqldb, administration, pentaho

I'm trying to get Pentaho's BI Server 3.10 up and running on CentOS and MySQL. I've followed the steps provided by Prashant Raju on his web site (and that have worked once before). The BI Server is running, but I can't get Pentaho's Administration Console (PAC) to start using the MySQL database. It always falls back to searching for a non-existant instance of HSQLDB's. Apparently everything is configured as should've been - obviously it's not, though...

Hope someone here can help me out, I'm quite lost here!

Thanks in advance,
Gustavo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, once I had moved administration console from its original place to an existing tomcat instance, I should have edited the file 
[pentaho-home-folder]/administration-console/resource/config/console.xml

As is explained on [pablotips's blogspot](http://pablotips.blogspot.com.br/p/installing-tomcat-and-pentaho.html).
Thanks, dude!

Answer (score 0):

In your `webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/web.xml`, look for the lines

```
<!-- [BEGIN HSQLDB DATABASES]
<context-param> 
     <param-name>hsqldb-databases</param-name> 
     <param-value>sampledata@../../data/hsqldb/sampledata,hibernate@../../data/hsqldb/hibernate,quartz@../../data/hsqldb/quartz</param-value>
</context-param>
[END HSQLDB DATABASES] -->
```

and

```
<!-- [BEGIN HSQLDB STARTER]
<listener> 
     <listener-class>org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.HsqldbStartupListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
[END HSQLDB STARTER] -->
```

Comment out or delete those 2 lines.